# Implementing a vertical sidebar menu in swt?

Tags: java, menu, swt

Currently I am using a Tree as a menu.

But is there a way to implement a beautiful Menu in SWT? (see picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollapsibleButtons` looks like good fit but it won't give you exact look and feel. I did implement custom menu structure with tree before. Here is the approach, you can actually customize `Treeitem` to look like what you want.  Go through below article, you can figure out how to custom paint or adjust bounds of `TreeItems`

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about "beautiful", but there is the [`CollapsibleButtons`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/collapsiblebuttons/collapsiblebuttons.php) widget from the [Nebula Project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/).

It looks like this:

[image]

If that's not what you were thinking of, I would suggest [creating your own](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) `Button` that looks like the ones in your screenshot and adding them with a `RowLayout` to a `Composite` that acts as a sidebar.